Why does PreAuthorizeAuthorizationManager does not pick up the Authenication object set in the Security Context?
I am using Spring boot 3.3.3 and Spring security latest versions. I did a custom JWT security filter and have successfully authenticated a user and have set some granted authorities in the authentication object. The filter successfully sets the authentication object in the Security context as well as part of the filter chain. I have use @PreAuthorize at method level for authorisation.
Then I keep the security jwt access token in the header and make a API call.
However the PreAuthorizeAuthorizationManager does not use the authentication object from the security context but rather denies the API call for the user even though it has been granted authority.
Can anyone explain should I write a custom AuthorizationManager ?
I am trying to use spring implementations but seems I have to customise AuthoizationManager.
